# How to calculate Pi filter for RF with PCB antenna - Nordic nRF52832

Tags: rf, filter, bluetooth-low-energy, nrf52832

I have finished the layout of a bluetooth beacon based on SoC nRF52832 of Nordic, there is a Pi filter between the IC pin and the antenna that use the AN043 drawing of Texas.

AN043: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra117d/swra117d.pdf

How can I calculate/estimate the inputs for this online tool? Like Source Resistance, Source Reactance, Load Resistance, Load Reactance, Q Factor, the frequency I know is 2.4GHz.

https://www.eeweb.com/tools/pi-match

Is there informations that I should get with the manufacturer of the chip? (nRF52832)

I want estimate intial values for inductor L2, and capacitors C16 and C17. The 0.8pF cap. and 3.9nH inductor is required according to their application document.

I am asking this because I am not familiar with RF circuit calculations.
Regards.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ask directly Nordic. They are quite helpful on this. If necessary, you can even send the board to Norway for fine tuning and measurements.

Comment: What impedance does the chip expect to see? What is the antenna impedance? The rest is maths.

Comment: Just wanted to add: I'm working on an 833-based design and Nordic recommended me **copy** the entire antenna-filter network directly from their DK. You can find the hardware files from Nordic Info Center.

Comment: @Andyaka They said: "The chip expects to see 50 ohms, outside of C11+L1. Even if you know the antenna impedance you need to measure this, calculating it will not be accurate enough. The antenna impedance will be quite close to 50 ohms, but will vary depending on the layout and PCB size/shape." PCB is FR4 1.6mm

Comment: So, what are you actually trying to find out with this question? I may have missed something but there doesn't appear to be anything you can expect this site to deliver that will help you.

Comment: There are tables to calculate impedance of source matching network. The antenna impedance would be about 50 Ω. Just calculate impedance of the circuit left to C16 would to be  thevenin impedance of the network. Put that as  \$Z_{th} with R_s and X_s in the calculator above. R_L would be 50Ω. X_L would be 0Ω. \$

Answer (score 2):

You must choose source and load impedance as lumped elements and plot BODE amplitude and phase in [Falstad's filter emulator.](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+5+50+5+46%0A%25+0+16905175966.395636%0Al+288+128+288+192+0+3.9e-9+0%0Ac+224+128+288+128+0+8e-13+0%0AO+368+128+416+128+0%0Ag+288+192+288+208+0%0A170+192+128+160+128+3+10+150+5+0.5%0Ag+368+192+368+208+0%0Ac+368+128+368+192+0+3.4999999999999997e-13+0%0Aw+368+128+288+128+0%0Ar+224+128+192+128+0+47%0Ao+4+128+0+34+5+0.00009765625+0+-1%0Ao+2+128+0+34+5+0.00009765625+1+-1%0A)

There I added some IC input cap to tune to 2.4GHz and converted LPF to BPF.

[image]